# What is the runtime complexity of this pseudocode?

Tags: time-complexity

I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity of pseudocodes.

```
p=10;
num=0;
plimit=100000;
    for (i = p; i<=plimit; i++)
        for (j = 1; j<=i; j++)
            num = num + 1;
```

I think it will be a linear search, but just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

It's not linear time. The inner loop has the incremental operation cost as i increments on each iteration, so 1+2+3...+n gives you O(n<sup>2</sup>) because of `(n+1)*(n/2)`.